How to get status of query definition
I want to get the status of a query definition. I am interested in knowing if it ended up in an error or not.
I run query definitions from a script, but I cannot access the information about whether they completed successfully or not.

Outside of an Automation, that information isn't available -- as far as I know.
Perhaps if the InteractionObjectID property on the QueryDefinition was retrievable, but it's not.

can't we get TaskId using the query definition Perform method and use TaskID to retrieve the Query's status using SOAP API? I'm just getting your thoughts on this.

The PerformResult object is also not retrievable.  It could be there's a method for getting this using the InteractionObjectID, but I haven't found it.  I wouldn't expect there to be a solution to this, since running queries outside of an Automation isn't a common practice.  Most don't even know it's possible.
